# Current line in sass file

Tags: sass

Is it possible to get the current line of a sass file in a variable? Just as the `__LINE__` magic constant in PHP.

Or even better: is it possible to determine from witch file/line a sass @function was called?

Comment: I think [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/) does [just what you want](http://nex-3.com/posts/92-firesass-bridges-the-gap-between-sass-and-firebug), doesn't it?

Comment: What would you use this magic variable for?  The only information you can get regarding line numbers is by turning on the debugging features.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think didn't make it clear enough. I've got a @function that get's called (quite often), which needs to be replaced in some cases. I'm able to narrow down these cases inside the function based on its parameters, and I would like to print a warning with the file and line numbers where it has been called. Would be easier than grepping every function call and doing the calculation by hand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that.  You could use Sass to spit out a copy of the function call that you can copy/paste for grepping purposes: `@debug my-function-name($arg1, $arg2...)`

Comment: Isn't that what the [`@warn`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id9) directive is for? It should print a stylesheet stack trace along with the warning message.

Comment: `@warn` doesn't print the stacktrace, just the line number (which is in my `@function` and therefore not helpful). Perhaps `@warn` is somehow configurable to print the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @Philipp, this is interesting ... after a little experimentation, it looks to me that the full trace is printed if the `@warn` is inside a mixin, but if it's inside a function, only the line number is printed. I wonder if this is a bug in SASS?